# Inject a component's ATTRIBUTE into a Service

Tags: angular, angular13

So I'm trying to make a service that will accept a parameter on construction. Idea is that it is not provided at root, but will be used similarly by several components. Each component would use a different instance of the service.

The service looks something like:

```
    import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core'; @Injectable()
        
    export class SpecialService {
          constructor(
            @Inject('myArray') public myArray: any[]
          ) {}
    // Bunch of functions intended to mutate this array.
 

}
```

Then in a component I might have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  templateUrl: './thing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thing.component.css'],
  providers: [
    ArrayService,
    {
      provide: 'myArray',
      useValue: []
    }
  ]
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
  private arrayService: ArrayService
){}

  dummy_array = // an array for purposes of testing

  ngOninit(){
  const httpArray = // get something from an HTTP call
  }
}
```

So What I want to do is rather than providing the service with a static empty Array, I want to provide it the dummy_array and eventually httpArray. I haven't found a way to do that without making simply binding myArray as a public attribute. I'd like to avoid that if possible, but most importantly, I'd like to use inject() properly here.

Comment: Don't take this as me being rude. I just need clarification. This design doesn't make sense.    There is nothing wrong with a public property in this scenario. Can you show us how you're mutating the array in the service and what input/output looks like? Maybe we can give better recommendations that way.

Comment: But if you're not actually using is as injected class, why not use it simply as external helper class, import it to your components, declare it in their constructors, and call its functions from the components when needed? If the class is just mutating the data and returning it, then it's just a helper class that's doing the repetitive work needed by several components.